# Fan Control Usage Ubuntu 18.04 where fans controlled by the BIOS

Tags: 18.04, overheating, fan, lm-sensors

Cannot control fans on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS installed on [Dream Machines Notebook](https://dreammachines.eu/en/laptop_details/G1060-15EU33) with Clevo mainboard and Discrete NVidia GPU. Fans are always working even when usage CPU 1-2% (`sensors`) and GPU 1% (`nvidia-smi`). It
s pretty annoying to always have fans on.

By the way, On Windows (as 2nd OS dual-boot via GRUB2 on this notebook fans are **works fine** as needed)

Fan sensors are not detected using `sudo sensors-detect`

```
sensors
pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +48.0°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)

iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +38.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I tried to add boot parameters to my grub config in /etc/default/grub (not together). apply the changes by `sudo update-grub` and `reboot` and rerun `sudo sensors-detect` but it didn't help me to specify fans and all

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi="
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

[tlp-stat pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/KapybwFD) with `acpi_osi=Linux` logs

[tlp-stat pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/0pBL4khF) with `acpi_osi=` logs

fan and thermal_zone proc files are not existed

```
/proc/acpi/fan: No such file or directory
/proc/acpi/thermal_zone: No such file or directory
```

`fwts fan` gives me no feedback 
[fwts fan pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/fDmfabAL)

```
$hardinfo
```

[image]

Motherboard in `hardinfo` gives **Not Applicable / N8xxEP6 (Dream Machines)**
Maybe this is somehow relates to the problem?

There is an assumption that **notebook has no ACPI support for fans at all, they seem to be completely controlled by the BIOS**. By the way, keyboard
lightning always brights high (without changing brightness) even when I'm in BIOS as well as sitting in Ubuntu. So, assumption with fans completely controlled by the BIOS can be True.

But anyway maybe there is something that I can do to make fans work on Linux? Can someone explain is it possible to make them work or not if for example fans are completely controlled by the BIOS?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Assumptions can ruin your whole day. Your own screenshot shows that thermal zone directories are present. Just look in /sys/class/thermal ... ;-)